# Using Riemann-Roch to guarantee a pole at $P$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

As an easy consequence of Riemann-Roch, for a point $P$ on a curve $X$, we can show that there is some function regular everywhere but $P$. We can start by choosing $n$ large enough such that $h^0(X, \mathcal{L}(nP)) > 1$, and so we get a non constant rational function $f \in K(X)$, but this alone just gives us that $\text{ord}_P(f) > -n$. How do we proceed from here to show that in fact $f$ must have $\text{ord}_P(f)<0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the idea is that there cannot be a (non constant) function with no poles, since the only possible pole for $f$ is $P$, it must really be a pole.

Comment: [corollary 4.8 p. 77](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~schlag/bookweb.pdf) : an holomorphic function on a **compact** Riemann surface is constant

Comment: @ufabao [The proof is with the maximum modulus principle](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881742/holomorphic-functions-on-a-complex-compact-manifold-are-only-constants) !

Comment: You can see it from topology, there is not non constant map from a compact space to $\mathbb{C}$. One can also see it from Riemann Roch letting $D=0$, $l(0)=0-g+i(0)+1$, and $i(D)\leq g$.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus "compact space" ? As I understand it, the property we need is that there is  an open (in the $\mathbb{C}$ topology, so isomorphic to the unit disk) around each point $p \in M$, and that $M$ is compact. If $f(p)$ is holomorphic on $M$ then $|f(p)|$ has a maximum at $p_0$, and with  $\phi$ a chart from $U \ni p$ to the unit disk, then $f(\phi^{-1}(z))$ is holomorphic and has a local maximum at $\phi(p_0)$