Why do we need to prove extension lemmas?
I'm studying Lee's smooth manifolds, and time and time again, whether it be for functions in $\mathcal{C}^\infty(M)$ where $M$ is a manifold, or for vector fields over $M$, or for sections of vector bundles, he proves extension lemmas which say that if we can define such an object on a subset of the entire space, then there must exist some other object on the entire space which has a restriction equal to the initial object.
Intuitively I don't see why this requires proof, are there any instances where this fails? Does there for example exist an object defined on a subset for which there does not exist an object defined on an entire set with an equal restriction?

In functional analysis, for infinite dimensional Banach spaces you need to have some property to guarantee the existence of a lift

These extension lemmas are a bit special to working with smooth things over $\mathbb{R}$. If you work with analytic things over $\mathbb{C}$, then for instance all global analytic functions on the projective line $\mathbb{C}\mathbb{P}^1$ (which is a complex manifold) are constant, while you can locally define an analytic function which is non-constant and hence cannot be extended globally. We heavily use the existence of bump functions in the smooth case over $\mathbb{R}$, which are not available in other settings.

And there is a more general such result on all compact complex manifolds: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/881742/holomorphic-functions-on-a-complex-compact-manifold-are-only-constants.  This is why the "right" global function concept when working with compact complex manifolds is holomorphic functions to $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ rather than holomorphic functions to $\mathbf C$.  Holomorphic  functions to $\mathbf P^1(\mathbf C)$ may be called meromorphic functions to avoid confusion.

The function
$$\begin{array}{ccc} \mathbb R \setminus \{0\} & \longrightarrow & \mathbb R \\ x & \longmapsto & \dfrac 1x \end{array}$$
cannot be the restriction of a continuous function $\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$.

In a similar spirit, $f:\mathbb R^n\setminus{0}\to\mathbb R,x\mapsto|x|$ is an example of a smooth function that is not the restriction of a smooth function $\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ despite being the restriction of a continuous one.

@peabrainiac good one !
